# longtable - different amount of table-rows per page - why?

Tags: longtable

With the following example you get three pages of table rows.

Page 1 contains table row 1 to table row 41, i.e. 41 table rows.
Page 2 contains table row 42 to table row 83, i.e. 42 table rows.
Page 3 contains table row 84 to table row 100, i.e., 17 table rows.

Why do page 1 and page 2 not contain an equal amount of rows?

If with the example the page where the longtable starts is enlarged by an amount as small as 1sp via uncommenting the line `\enlargethispage{1sp}`, both page 1 and page 2 contain 42 rows.

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{2}

\newcount\scratchcnt
\newtoks\scratchtoks
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\scratchloop[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \scratchcnt=#1\relax
  \scratchtoks{\endgroup}%
  \loop 
    \scratchtoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\scratchtoks\romannumeral`\^^@#3}%
  \ifnum\scratchcnt<#2\relax
    \advance\scratchcnt by 1\relax
  \repeat
  \the\scratchtoks
}%

\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
% \maxdepth\z@
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}

%\enlargethispage{1sp}%

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline number&text\\\hline\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{This is a clever remark.}\\\hline\endfoot
\scratchloop{1}%
            {100}%
            {\expandafter\hbox\expandafter{\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\the\scratchcnt}{\hphantom{100}\llap}}%
            &text\\}%
\end{longtable}%

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Edit, January 31, 2022:

I **think** it may have to do with line 149 `\maxdepth\z@` of [longtable.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf)—this is under the comment *"If the foot is non empty, reduce the `\vsize` and `\@colroom` accordingly."*:

If line 149 "`\maxdepth\z@`" is commented out, both page 1 and page 2 have 42 rows.

If line 149  "`\maxdepth\z@`" is enabled and in the preamble you add another `\maxdepth\z@`, both page 1 and page 2 have 41 rows.

When you trace the value which `\maxdepth` has when typesetting a row of the table, you see that `\maxdepth` is 0 when shipping the 1st page of the longtable and is `5` when shipping subsequent pages of the page:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{2}

\newcount\scratchcnt
\newtoks\scratchtoks
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\scratchloop[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \scratchcnt=#1\relax
  \scratchtoks{\endgroup}%
  \loop 
    \scratchtoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\scratchtoks\romannumeral`\^^@#3}%
  \ifnum\scratchcnt<#2\relax
    \advance\scratchcnt by 1\relax
  \repeat
  \the\scratchtoks
}%

\pagestyle{plain}

\def\mymessagething#1{%
  \llap{#1}\message{^^JLine #1: Maxdepth: \the\maxdepth}%
}%

\makeatletter
%\maxdepth\z@
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}

%\enlargethispage{1sp}%

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline number&text\\\hline\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{This is a clever remark.}\\\hline\endfoot
\scratchloop{1}%
            {100}%
            {\expandafter
             \hbox\expandafter{%
               \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\the\scratchcnt}{\hphantom{100}\mymessagething}%
             }%
            &text\\}%
\end{longtable}%

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

Console-output:

```
$ pdflatex-dev test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/11/23 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

Line 1: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 2: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 3: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 4: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 5: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 6: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 7: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 8: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 9: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 10: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 11: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 12: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 13: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 14: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 15: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 16: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 17: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 18: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 19: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 20: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 21: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 22: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 23: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 24: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 25: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 26: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 27: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 28: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 29: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 30: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 31: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 32: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 33: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 34: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 35: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 36: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 37: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 38: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 39: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 40: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 41: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 42: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 43: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 44: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 45: Maxdepth: 0.0pt 
Line 46: Maxdepth: 0.0pt [1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/
updmap/pdftex.map}] 
Line 47: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 48: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 49: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 50: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 51: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 52: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 53: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 54: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 55: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 56: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 57: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 58: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 59: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 60: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 61: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 62: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 63: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 64: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 65: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 66: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 67: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 68: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 69: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 70: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 71: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 72: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 73: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 74: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 75: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 76: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 77: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 78: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 79: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 80: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 81: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 82: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 83: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 84: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 85: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 86: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 87: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 88: Maxdepth: 5.0pt [2] 
Line 89: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 90: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 91: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 92: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 93: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 94: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 95: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 96: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 97: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 98: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 99: Maxdepth: 5.0pt 
Line 100: Maxdepth: 5.0pt [3] (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist
/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (3 pages, 19397 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: How can 40 or more rows fit on a landscape page?

Comment: @barbarabeeton LaTeX does it. Just compile the example and you see.

Comment: I've pinged David Carlisle in the chat about this.  He will look later at my question about the switch from landscape to portrait, but in the meantime he said that there's a space before a `longtable`.  Indeed there is -- specified by `\newskip\LTpre \LTpre=\bigskipamount` and applied at the start of the table.  Line 63 in the `.sty` file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you very much :-) It is not a matter of urgency. Maybe the issue is not that much about portrait/landscape. I think it is about edge cases of page-heights/`\vsize`s where different amounts of table-rows can occur. Probably minimal differences in row-heights are the reason. Probably the longtable-algorithm. I don't know. I am just curious, but right now, my analgesics don't allow me to review the longtable package code at my leisure - I perceive everything as if through the lens of a monocular, which is an interesting experience, but doesn't increase my mental capacity. ;-)

Comment: I do hope you will feel better.  I examined the code after David commented that a longtable is always preceded by a (v)space, and found it.  This is actually logical (to me at least), since longtables often follow text on a page, where space will be wanted.  I looked in the `.sty` file, not the `.dtx`, so there was no commentary.  The `.dtx` might be more instructive.  Anyhow, look for `\LTpre` and you should see where it's happening.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\LTpre` is vertical glue, `\bigskipamount` by default. I think it is discarded at the start of a page. If with my mwe the page where the longtable starts is enlarged by an amount as small as 1sp, both page 1 and page 2 contain 42 rows. So I think/guess the difference is not caused by `\LTpre`.

Comment: Definitely off-topic: geometry's `{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}` may be expressed more succinctly as `{margin=1.5cm}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. (I never use geometry. Just this time for shortening the code for the example .)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it:

longtable's output-routine, `\LT@output`, in [line 384](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf#page.25) respective [line 396](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf#page.26) of longtable.sty does `\@makecol` before `\@outputpage`.

`\@makecol` in turn is defined in the LaTeX 2ε-kernel—[source2e.pdf, File V ltoutput.dtx, page 890](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#page.890), says:

> `\@makecol` : Makes the contents of `\box255` plus the accumulated footnotes, plus the floats in `\@toplist` and `\@botlist`, into a single column of height `\@colht` (unless the page height has been locally changed), which it puts into box `\@outputbox`. It puts boxes in `\@midlist` back onto `\@freelist` **and restores `\maxdepth`.**

Line 514 of that file says that the assignment for restoring `\maxdepth` is global.

So whenever the output-routine did its work, `\maxdepth` is globally "restored" to the value currently stored in `\@maxdepth`.

Therefore `\LT@start`'s setting `\maxdepth` to `\z@` in [line 149 of longtable.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf#page.17)  in case the table-foot is not empty has effect only until the output-routine has produced the first page of the longtable. With subsequent pages `\maxdepth` is back to `\@maxdepth`.

In the example below I modified `\LT@start` to also set `\@maxdepth`.

But I doubt that this is the best approach:

- This way the value `\@maxdepth` is reset as soon as the group forming the longtable-environment ends.
  But the modified value of `\maxdepth` (which by the output-routine/`\@makecol` is restored globally) is in effect until the output-routine acted the next time after the longtable-environment ended.
- I don't know why `\maxdepth` is modified at all only in case the table-foot is not empty.
- I don't know how modifications affect nested longtable-environments.
- If `\maxdepth` is reset globally from a local value of `\@maxdepth`, `\maxdepth` should probably be reset globally at the end of the longtable-environment from the global value of `\@maxdepth` – but only in case the page holding the last portion of the long table does contain material not belonging to the long table as well.

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{2}

\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter

\newcount\scratchcnt
\newtoks\scratchtoks
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\scratchloop[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \scratchcnt=#1\relax
  \scratchtoks{\endgroup}%
  \loop 
    \scratchtoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\scratchtoks\romannumeral`\^^@#3}%
  \ifnum\scratchcnt<#2\relax
    \advance\scratchcnt by 1\relax
  \repeat
  \the\scratchtoks
}%

\def\mymessagething#1{%
  \llap{#1}\immediate\write0{Line #1: \string\maxdepth: \the\maxdepth; \string\@maxdepth: \the\@maxdepth}%
}%

\def\LT@start{%                                                            %-line 114 of longtable.sty
  \let\LT@start\endgraf                                                    %-line 115 of longtable.sty
  \endgraf\penalty\z@\vskip\LTpre\endgraf                                  %-line 116 of longtable.sty
  \ifdim \pagetotal<\pagegoal \else                                        %-line 117 of longtable.sty
    \dimen@=\pageshrink                                                    %-line 118 of longtable.sty
   \advance \dimen@ 1sp %                                                  %-line 119 of longtable.sty
   \kern\dimen@\penalty 9999\endgraf \kern-\dimen@                         %-line 120 of longtable.sty
  \fi                                                                      %-line 121 of longtable.sty
  \dimen@\pagetotal                                                        %-line 122 of longtable.sty
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi     %-line 123 of longtable.sty
  \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi     %-line 124 of longtable.sty
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\LT@foot                                              %-line 125 of longtable.sty
  \edef\LT@reset@vfuzz{\vfuzz\the\vfuzz\vbadness\the\vbadness\relax}%      %-line 126 of longtable.sty
  \vfuzz\maxdimen                                                          %-line 127 of longtable.sty
  \vbadness\@M                                                             %-line 128 of longtable.sty
  \setbox\tw@\copy\z@                                                      %-line 129 of longtable.sty
  \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox                                %-line 130 of longtable.sty
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%                                           %-line 131 of longtable.sty
  \LT@reset@vfuzz                                                          %-line 132 of longtable.sty
  \advance\dimen@ \ht                                                      %-line 133 of longtable.sty
       \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi               %-line 134 of longtable.sty
  \advance\dimen@\dp                                                       %-line 135 of longtable.sty
       \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi               %-line 136 of longtable.sty
  \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal                                               %-line 137 of longtable.sty
  \ifdim \dimen@>\z@                                                       %-line 138 of longtable.sty
    \vfil\break                                                            %-line 139 of longtable.sty
  \else                                                                    %-line 140 of longtable.sty
    \ifdim\pageshrink>\z@\pageshrink\z@\fi                                 %-line 141 of longtable.sty
  \fi                                                                      %-line 142 of longtable.sty
  \global\@colroom\@colht                                                  %-line 143 of longtable.sty
  \ifvoid\LT@foot\else                                                     %-line 144 of longtable.sty
 %   \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot                                            %-line 145 of longtable.sty
    \global\advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot                                      %-line 146 of longtable.sty
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot                                   %-line 147 of longtable.sty
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@            %-line 148 of longtable.sty
    %%%%% Here:  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     % addition by me
    \@maxdepth\z@                                                          % addition by me
    \maxdepth\z@                                                           %-line 149 of longtable.sty
  \fi                                                                      %-line 150 of longtable.sty
  \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\copy\LT@head\else\box\LT@firsthead\fi\nobreak       %-line 151 of longtable.sty
  \output{\LT@output}}%                                                    %-line 152 of longtable.sty


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline number&text\\\hline\endhead
\hline\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{This is a clever remark.}\\\hline\endfoot
\scratchloop{1}%
            {100}%
            {\expandafter
             \hbox\expandafter{%
              \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\the\scratchcnt}{\hphantom{100}\mymessagething}%
             }%
            &text\\}%
\end{longtable}%

\message{^^JAfter longtable:}%

\message{^^J\string\maxdepth: \the\maxdepth; \string\@maxdepth: \the\@maxdepth}%

\newpage

\message{^^JAfter newpage:}

\message{^^J\string\maxdepth: \the\maxdepth; \string\@maxdepth: \the\@maxdepth}%

% \restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

With this modification both the first and the second page contain 41 table rows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The terminal-output looks like this:

```
$ pdflatex-dev test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/11/23 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
Line 1: \maxdepth: 5.0pt; \@maxdepth: 5.0pt
Line 2: \maxdepth: 5.0pt; \@maxdepth: 5.0pt
Line 3: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 4: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 5: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 6: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 7: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 8: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 9: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 10: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 11: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 12: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 13: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 14: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 15: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 16: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 17: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 18: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 19: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 20: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 21: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 22: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 23: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 24: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 25: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 26: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 27: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 28: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 29: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 30: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 31: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 32: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 33: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 34: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 35: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 36: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 37: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 38: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 39: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 40: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 41: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 42: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 43: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 44: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 45: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 46: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Line 47: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 48: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 49: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 50: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 51: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 52: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 53: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 54: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 55: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 56: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 57: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 58: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 59: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 60: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 61: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 62: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 63: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 64: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 65: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 66: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 67: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 68: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 69: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 70: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 71: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 72: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 73: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 74: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 75: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 76: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 77: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 78: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 79: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 80: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 81: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 82: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 83: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 84: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 85: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 86: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
[2]
Line 87: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 88: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 89: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 90: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 91: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 92: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 93: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 94: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 95: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 96: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 97: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 98: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 99: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt
Line 100: \maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 0.0pt

After longtable: 
\maxdepth: 0.0pt; \@maxdepth: 5.0pt [3] 
After newpage: 
\maxdepth: 5.0pt; \@maxdepth: 5.0pt (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2020/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (3 pages, 19391 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```